# Access violation reading location 0x000000148965F000

Tags: c++, c, ffmpeg

I tried to encode BMP Images, which i get from a buffer and store it as a H264 Video. I am stuck with these errors the arrive randomly and repeatedly

I am using Visual Studio 2012

1) Access violation reading location 0x000000148965F000.

2)Heap corruption

The debug shows the error at this point

```
    struct SwsContext* fooContext = sws_getContext(_imgWidth,_imgHeight,PIX_FMT_RGB32,c->width,c->height,PIX_FMT_YUV420P, SWS_FAST_BILINEAR,NULL,NULL,NULL);
                    sws_scale(fooContext, inpic->data, inpic->linesize, 0, c->height, outpic->data, outpic->linesize);    // converting frame size and format
```

I guess the read violation happens due to non - pre initialized values. But i couldnt exactly understand why. I have also attached part of the code below

```
PagedImage *inImg = getUpdatedInputImage(0);
        ML_CHECK(inImg);
        ImageVector imgExt = inImg->getImageExtent();
        if ((imgExt.x == _imgWidth) && (imgExt.y == _imgHeight))
        {
            if (((imgExt.x % 4) == 0) && ((imgExt.y % 4) == 0))
            {
               _numFramesFld->setIntValue(_numFramesFld->getIntValue() + 1);
                MLFree(unicodeFilename);
                // configure header
                //BITMAPINFO bitmapInfo
                // read out input image and write output image into video
                // get input image as an array
                void* imgData = NULL;
                SubImageBox imageBox(imgExt); // get the whole image
                getTile(inImg, imageBox, MLuint8Type, &imgData);
                MLuint8* iData = (MLuint8*)imgData;
                // since we have only images with
                // a z-ext of 1, we can compute the c stride as follows
                int cStride = _imgWidth * _imgHeight;
                int offset  = 0;
                MLuint8 r=0, g=0, b=0;
                // pointer into the bitmap that is
                // used to write images into an video
                UCHAR* dst = (UCHAR*)_bits;
                for (int y = _imgHeight-1; y >= 0; y--)
                { // reversely scan the image. if y-rows of DIB are set in normal order, no compression will be available.
                    offset = _imgWidth * y;
                    for (int x = 0; x < _imgWidth; x++)
                    {
                        if (_isGreyValueImage)
                        {
                            r = iData[offset + x];
                            *dst++ = (UCHAR)r;
                            *dst++ = (UCHAR)r;
                            *dst++ = (UCHAR)r;
                        } 
                        else
                        {
                            b = iData[offset + x]; // windows bitmap need reverse order: bgr instead of rgb
                            g = iData[offset + x + cStride          ];
                            r = iData[offset + x + cStride + cStride];
                            *dst++ = (UCHAR)r;
                            *dst++ = (UCHAR)g;
                            *dst++ = (UCHAR)b;
                        }
                        // alpha channel in input image is ignored
                    }
                }
                outbuf_size = 100000 + c->width*c->height*(32>>3);      // allocate output buffer
                outbuf = static_cast<uint8_t *>(malloc(outbuf_size));
                fileName_ = (_outputFilenameFld->getStringValue()).c_str();
                FILE* f = fopen(fileName_,"wb");                    // opening video file for writing
                if(!f)
                {
                    _messageFld->setStringValue("Cannot open file");
                }
                else _messageFld->setStringValue("Opened video file for writing\n");

                //for(i=0;i<_numFramesFld->getIntValue();i++)
                //{
                    fflush(stdout);
                    int nbytes = avpicture_get_size(PIX_FMT_YUV420P, c->width, c->height);                                // allocating outbuffer
                    uint8_t* outbuffer = (uint8_t*)av_malloc(nbytes*sizeof(uint8_t));
                    AVFrame* inpic = avcodec_alloc_frame();                                                               // mandatory frame allocation
                    AVFrame* outpic = avcodec_alloc_frame();
                    //outpic->pts = (int64_t)((float)i * (1000.0/((float)(c->time_base.den))) * 90);                        // setting frame pts
                    avpicture_fill((AVPicture*)inpic,(uint8_t*)dst, PIX_FMT_RGB32, c->width, c->height);                            // fill image with input screenshot
                    avpicture_fill((AVPicture*)outpic, outbuffer, PIX_FMT_YUV420P, c->width, c->height);                  // clear output picture for buffer copy
                    av_image_alloc(outpic->data, outpic->linesize, c->width, c->height, c->pix_fmt, 1); 

                    inpic->data[0] += inpic->linesize[0]*(c->height-1);                                                   // flipping frame
                    inpic->linesize[0] = -inpic->linesize[0];                                                             // flipping frame

                    struct SwsContext* fooContext = sws_getContext(_imgWidth,_imgHeight,PIX_FMT_RGB32,c->width,c->height,PIX_FMT_YUV420P, SWS_FAST_BILINEAR,NULL,NULL,NULL);
                    sws_scale(fooContext, inpic->data, inpic->linesize, 0, c->height, outpic->data, outpic->linesize);    // converting frame size and format
                    out_size = avcodec_encode_video(c, outbuf, outbuf_size, outpic);                                      // encoding video
                    _messageFld->setStringValue("Encoding frame %3d (size=%5d)\n");
                     fwrite(outbuf, 1, out_size, f);
                     delete [] dst;                                                                                         // freeing memory
                    av_free(outbuffer);     
                    av_free(inpic);
                    av_free(outpic);
                    av_free(fooContext);
                    DeleteObject(_hbitmap);

                    for(int Z = 0; Z<out_size; i++)
                    {
                        fflush(stdout);
                        out_size = avcodec_encode_video(c, outbuf, outbuf_size, outpic);                                              // encode the delayed frames
                        fwrite(outbuf, 1, out_size, f);
                    }
                    //outbuf[0] = 0x00;
                    //outbuf[1] = 0x00;                                                                                               // add sequence end code to have a real mpeg file
                    //outbuf[2] = 0x01;
                    //outbuf[3] = 0xb7;
                    //fwrite(outbuf, 1, 4, f);
                    fclose(f);
                    avcodec_close(c);                                                                                               // freeing memory
                    free(outbuf);
                    av_free(c);
                    printf("Closed codec and Freed\n");
                }
            }
```

Comment: You may want to tag this as C. You may find more people who can read this code in that tag.

Comment: valgrind valgrind, and valgrind.

Comment: @bmargulies doesn't support Windows, doesn't support Windows, and (still) doesn't support Windows.

Comment: @NigelHarper debug code on linux, debug code on linx, debug code on linux :-). VirtualBox is free.

Answer (score 1):

Access violation could be tricky to debug.
Since you have a Read Access Violation, it could be that somewhere you have run over your pointers with data and only now, when you try to read from there, you get the exception.

I recommend you use GFLAGS with Full PageHeap to pinpoint exactly the location of your AccessViolation:

gflags /p /enable ImageFileName /full.

[GFlags and PageHeap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff549561%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

I hope this will help

Comment: Hi, I couldnt find the GFLAGS in VS, I do have the Windows SDK but i couldn't find the Windbg.exe file too... How could i exactly enable this flag?? in Visual studio...

Comment: in here: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/hh852365.aspx
scroll down to download the:
Standalone Debugging Tools for Windows 8.1 (WinDbg)

and then it will be under:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Debuggers\x86

Comment: @user3012914 it's easier to use the gflags from command prompt just as the usage i sent you:
gflags /p /enable ImageFileName /full
I find the UI too complex for that use...
just remember to disable the full page heap once you finish with it, as the documentation states, your process will consume much more memory with gflags enabled.

Comment: Hey.. I am trying to do it.. yet that doesn't help me. I am still stuck with the same error. But access violation with different application in this case "MevisLab.dll". I am not sure why..

Comment: That is exactly what i was telling you about...
once you use GFlags, you get the exception as it happens in the first time.
Sometimes your code or 3rd parties code, writes over places in the memory which belong to your application, but once your application gets to read from those parts, all pointers there are now pointing to areas of memory which does not belong to your application.

Comment: Hi I tried using gflags, I get the same error again at the same point **Unhandled exception at 0x0000000069997CB5 (avcodec-55.dll) in MeVisLab.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000050.** after activating gflags... But the problem is i dont exactly understand why this happens...

Comment: I just notice I didn't tell you that, when you run GFlags, your process needs to be running for the flags to be updated in the registry.. then you need to close your app and start it.
Another thing to remember, when you run a program from Visual Studio, your process name will be different: processName.vhost.exe.
Personally, I run my process not from VS and then either attach to it with VS with breakpoint on AccessViolation or run **adplus -Crash -NoDumpOnFirst -pn <ProcessName> -o d:\ADPlus_Dumps** and then view the dump in WinDbg